# How to get headless raw audio data from iPhone's mic into NSData

Tags: iphone, audio-recording

I need to record 3 sec of headles raw audio data: PCM 11025 samples per second, 16 bit mono and then send it as base64 encoded string.

With AVAudioRecorder I can record .CAf file and access it at any time, but the question is: how can I get headless raw audio data from recorded file into NSData object?

Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796064/avaudiorecorder-initwithurl-file-type-documentation