# AVAudioRecorder initWithURL file type documentation

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, audioqueue

`AvAudioRecorder` has an init method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                   settings:(NSDictionary *)settings
                      error:(NSError **)outError
```

And a "magic" behavior is [partially documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/index.html):

> URL
>
> The file system location to record to. The file type to record to is inferred from the file extension included in this parameter’s value.

**Is there any further documentation of this feature? Specifically, what are the supported file extensions? And is there any way to support raw output?**

Related:

- [How to record using AVAudioRecorder without the .caf container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170517/how-to-record-using-avaudiorecorder-without-the-caf-container)
- [How to use AVAudioRecorder data and convert it to raw audio for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328357/how-to-use-avaudiorecorder-data-and-convert-it-to-raw-audio-for-c)
- [How can I Access/extract raw(headless) audio data from a caf file on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982596/how-can-i-access-extract-rawheadless-audio-data-from-a-caf-file-on-iphone)