# Recording with AVAudioSession - Why do I get more bytes than expected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I'm setting up a recording session as follow:

```
NSString *audioFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"temp.bin"];
_audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = @{
        AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: @NO,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: @NO,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityHigh),
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: @128000,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: @32,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @2,
        AVSampleRateKey: @44100.0f
    };
```

According to this, the number of bytes should be:

`bytes = 4 * 44100 * 2 * 2 = 705600 bytes`

But actually when I get the recorded data:

```
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
  if (flag) {
  
    NSData *recordedAudioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_audioFileURL options:0 error:&error];
    NSUInteger recordedAudioLength = [recordedAudioData length];
```

The `recordedAudioLenght` is slightly bigger: `709696 bytes`.

How can I avoid this? Is the problem how I setup the recording or how I retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data from AVAudioRecorder is not just raw bytes. It's in a container, in this case the [Apple Core Audio Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAFSpec/CAF_spec/CAF_spec.html) or CAF. The extra 4kB are the file header and chunk headers, plus padding ("free" chunk).

I don't believe there's any way to get AVAudioRecorder to output audio samples without a format. [You can find many versions of that question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796064/avaudiorecorder-initwithurl-file-type-documentation) You would either need to use a lower-level tool like AVAudioSinkNode, or read the file after writing it and extract the samples.

(Note that your `AVEncoderBitRateKey` and `AVEncoderAudioQualityKey` keys don't apply here, since this is LPCM. But they're not hurting anything; they're just ignored.)

Comment: Thank you very much also for the note about the `AVEncoderBitRateKey` and `AVEncoderAuioQualityKey`.
In your opinion which would be the easiest way and format to write to temp file and retrieve as raw byte without headers?

Comment: Personally, I'd do this with AVAudioEngine and AVAudioSinkNode and skip writing a file entirely. Otherwise, CAF is very easy to parse. You just need to check the length of the audio chunk (there's only one), and throw everything else away. If you want pre-written code, I'd search for WAV parsers. They're common, and it's also a very simple format. (Just use the extension `.wav` and AVAudioRecorder will write that.) There's also AVAudioFile, which will parse it for you into an AVAudioPCMBuffer, which you can get the bytes from.

Comment: Thank you! As it seems that you know very well what you're talking about.. Can I ask one more question?
I'm trying to extract data from CAF using the last method you suggested.
However, I can only retrieve the data using `audioBuffer.floatChannelData` an if I use `audioBuffer.int32ChannelData` it crashes with bad memory access. Do you have an idea of why? My record settings are still the same of the post (having removed the useless one), and I think this is the issue, but I can't find how to modify them

Comment: Because the standard Core Audio format is deinterleaved 32-bit float. So there is no int32 channel data. You can convert the buffer using AVAudioConverter if you need ints. You can use the simpler `convert(to:from:)` interface for this conversion because it doesn't change the codec (LPCM) or sample rate.